# solve a bad Url to clean Url in php?

Tags: php

when I spide a website ,I got a lot of bad url like these.
`http://example.com/../../.././././1.htm`
`http://example.com/test/../test/.././././1.htm`
`http://example.com/.//1.htm`
`http://example.com/../test/..//1.htm`

all of these should be `http://example.com/1.htm`.
how to use PHP codes to do this ,thanks.

PS: I use http://snoopy.sourceforge.net/
I get a lot of repeated link in my database , the '`http://example.com/../test/..//1.htm`' should be '`http://example.com/1.htm`' .

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com/)

Comment: He told you--he spide it.  (What is "spide"? I'm not being facetious, I don't understand your question.)

Comment: How are these URLs being generated?

Comment: I think he mean to say spider. He's crawling a domain.

Comment: Why should `/.\./` and `//` both become `/`? They are semantically different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to be looking for a [algorithm to remove the dot segments](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-5.2.4):

```
function remove_dot_segments($abspath) {
    $ib = $abspath;
    $ob = '';
    while ($ib !== '') {
        if (substr($ib, 0, 3) === '../') {
            $ib = substr($ib, 3);
        } else if (substr($ib, 0, 2) === './') {
            $ib = substr($ib, 2);
        } else if (substr($ib, 0, 2) === '/.' && ($ib[2] === '/' || strlen($ib) === 2)) {
            $ib = '/'.substr($ib, 3);
        } else if (substr($ib, 0, 3) === '/..' && ($ib[3] === '/' || strlen($ib) === 3)) {
            $ib = '/'.substr($ib, 4);
            $ob = substr($ob, 0, strlen($ob)-strlen(strrchr($ob, '/')));
        } else if ($ib === '.' || $ib === '..') {
            $ib = '';
        } else {
            $pos = strpos($ib, '/', 1);
            if ($pos === false) {
                $ob .= $ib;
                $ib = '';
            } else {
                $ob .= substr($ib, 0, $pos);
                $ib = substr($ib, $pos);
            }
        }
    }
    return $ob;
}
```

This removes the `.` and `..` segments. Any removal of any other segment like an empty one (`//`) or `.\.` is not as per standard as it changes the semantics of the path.

Comment: https://github.com/glenscott/url-normalizer/blob/master/URLNormalizer.php Gumbo,thanks.you tell me how to find this codes.

Answer (score 1):

You could do it like this, assuming all the urls you have provided are expected tobe `http://example.com/1.htm`:

```
$test = array('http://example.com/../../../././.\./1.htm',
              'http://example.com/test/../test/../././.\./1.htm',
              'http://example.com/.//1.htm',
              'http://example.com/../test/..//1.htm');

foreach ($test as $url){
    $u = parse_url($url);
    $path = $u['scheme'].'://'.$u['host'].'/'.basename($u['path']);
    echo $path.'<br />'.PHP_EOL;
}
/* result
http://example.com/1.htm<br />
http://example.com/1.htm<br />
http://example.com/1.htm<br />
http://example.com/1.htm<br />
*/


//or as a function @lpc2138
function getRealUrl($url){ 
    $u = parse_url($url); 
    $path = $u['scheme'].'://'.$u['host'].'/'.basename($u['path']);

    $path .= (!empty($u['query'])) ? '?'.$u['query'] : ''; 
    return $path;
}
```

Comment: <pre>function getRealUrl($url){
 $u = parse_url($url);
 $path = $u['scheme'].'://'.$u['host'].'/'.basename($u['path']);</pre> thanks
 if($u['query']){
  $path .='?'.$u['query'];
 }
 return $path;
}

Comment: you didn't have that in your examples.

Comment: yes,it is just a example.not all.`http://www.example.com/datasheet/ds11015.html` should be `http://www.example.com/datasheet/ds11015.html`

Comment: @lpc2138 what is the difference between both given urls in your above comment?     "http://www.example.com/datasheet/ds11015.html" should be         "http://www.example.com/datasheet/ds11015.html" What I see is that they both are same.

Answer (score 0):

You could do some fancy regex but this works just fine.

```
fixUrl('http://example.com/../../../././.\./1.htm');

function fixUrl($str) {
    $str = str_replace('../', '', $str);
    $str = str_replace('./', '', $str);
    $str = str_replace('\.', '', $str);

    return $str;
}
```

Comment: You could just use `$str = str_replace(array('../','./','\.'), '', $str);`

Comment: your codes don't work,I just give you an example url.  my url is`http://example.com/../test/..//1.htm`

Comment: This doesn't do the actual traversal/collapsing of paths (like `/test/../` into `/`)